# How to vertical bottom align H1 to other text without using table and display

Tags: html, css

I tried to vertical align H1 text and normal text with bottom

```
<li>
  <span><h1>H1 text</h1></span>
  <span>normal text</span>
<li>
```

In my certain case,  display is set as block`display:block`  and I can not use table. Is there any other way, I can use to

Comment: Can you clarify which elements are set as display: block? The li? The span? Both?

Answer (score 0):

Set your span elements to use `display:inline-block;`.